# What's more efficient? One textview (spannable) or many standard textviews?

Tags: performance, textview, spannable

I want to have a textview like this:

*v.tr.* and *v.intr.* (past participle: **gone**, gerund: **going**)

and also with colors.

What is more efficient for my app? To use a single textview and to modify its parts (colors, style) with a spannable or to use many textviews with standard text style arranged side by side?

Thank you!

Comment: Found the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer yes.  One TextView with a spannable is more efficient, by a wide margin.